# Reactjs useeffect function run twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

**I don’t get it, could someone please help me with this problem, why is my `console.log` in my "randomFunc" log out data twice when I visit “Hello” page/component? What is causing the `console.log` log out second time?**

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Hello from "./Hello";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  const randomFunc = (dataFromHelloComponent) => {
    setData(dataFromHelloComponent);
    console.log(dataFromHelloComponent); /* <====  When I click "Go to Hello!" Link, this line log out data twice!? */
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Link to="/hello">Go to Hello!</Link>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route
          path="/hello"
          render={(props) => (
            <Hello {...props} randomFunc={randomFunc} data={data} />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hello.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function Hello({ randomFunc }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    randomFunc("Some random data!");
  }, [randomFunc]);

  return (
    <div className="hello">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**when I have “randomFunc” in Hello.js “useEffect” dependency, I get this in my browser console:**

Some random data!

Some random data!

**and if I remove “randomFunc” from Hello.js “useEffect” dependency, I get this in my browser console:**

Some random data!

React warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: ‘randomFunc’. Either include it or remove the…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating `randomFunc` every time `App` renders. Therefore the function is different, therefore `useEffect(..., [randomFunc])` triggers again. You can wrap `randomFunc` using [React.useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) so it's always the same actual function object returned.

Comment: Is there something to do with the "setData()" code? cause I found out that if I remove the "setData()" code, I'll get only one "Some random data!" instead of two "Some random data!" in my console.

Comment: Calling `setData` changes `App`'s state, which triggers a re-render. Then you create a brand new `randomFunc` which you pass to `Hello`, causing a re-render there, where the `useEffect` notices `randomFunc` changed, causing the effect to retrigger. So yes, indirectly it's caused by `setData`, but anything causing `App` to re-render would trigger this bug.

Comment: So basically, if I am writing my code this way the only solution I can do to prevent data log out twice or trigger the bug you were talking about, is to use react's useCallback?

Comment: Yes. The first render, it'll return the function you passed it. All following renders, it'll return that 1st function again, instead of recreating it again. That also means that if you're using variables out-of-scope, they will be stale. _You can add them to the dependency list, causing `useCallback` to recreate the function when any dependent value changes._ The only exception to this is `setData` and such. I _think_ they don't get recreated, but even if they do, React is smart enough that calling `setData` later will still work fine.

Comment: Hi, sorry just another quick question to the second comment, you said: "Calling ```setData``` changes App's state, which triggers a re-render. Then you create a brand new ```randomFunc``` which you pass to Hello, causing a re-render there, where the ```useEffect``` notices ```randomFunc``` changed, causing the effect to retrigger." but how come my code only logs out "Some random data!" twice and not causing an infinite loop? thanks and sorry again for asking another question after I accepted you answer.

Comment: @JustANewCoder Good question. React is smart enough that when you call `setData` with the same value, it won't actually queue a re-render. After all, you only need to re-render after a state **change**. Looking at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), it does actually say: `If your update function returns the exact same value as the current state, the subsequent rerender will be skipped completely.`. It also mentions it actually uses [`Object.is`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is) to compare.

Comment: So in conclusion the reason why my code log out value twice is because: when I visit the Hello.js page/component, the "useEffect" do an initial trigger which cause ```randomFun``` to run, and the function sets new value and log out "Some random data!"(first "Some random data!" log out in console), and because I set a new value to data state so it cause the App.js to re-render and create a new ```randomFun``` function then Hello.js "useEffect" detect ```randomFun``` that passed in from parent changed, so it triggers ```randomFunc``` again which cause it to log out second "Some random data!".

Comment: And for the reason why it didn't cause infinite loop is because: during the second time ```randomFunc``` execution, when react trying to set the value to data again, react found out the new value is the same as the old value so it skipped it, which no state change so App.js did not re-render and because App.js did not re-render, it did not create a new ```randomFunc``` function. Am I correct for both problem(log out twice and not causing infinite loop)?

Comment: Correct. And again, memoizing (e.g. using `useCallback` on) `randomFunc` should fix it. Your `randomFunc` wouldn't change, therefore the effect would only ever trigger once. `App` would still re-render twice, since the effect does still run once and changes the state.

Comment: Sorry, why would my App.js still re-render twice, I thought if I use useCallback, my App.js will only re-render once(re-render because of data state change)

Comment: I meant render twice (i.e. re-render once), I did word that badly. There's the first render, followed by the one caused by calling `setData` from `randomFunc`. _Although ideally, your component shouldn't care if it gets re-rendered extra times. React might be doing some weird partial rendering thing optimization._